# Apps hanging constantly on Catalina

Tags: catalina, crash, performance

I have apps hanging constantly on catalina.

Right now TextEdit is hanged. I have tried to close a textfile that was being edited and boom, textedit is hanged.

Looking at Activity Monitor I see two processes not responding:

1. com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService (TextEdit) (Not Responding)
2. TextEdit (Not Responding)

I have sampled both processes: [textedit](https://cl1p.net/textedit) and [openAndSavePanel](https://cl1p.net/openandsave)

Can someone take a look at these logs and see if the cause for the hangs can be detected?

NOTE: if I force quit TextEdit it will close but not open anymore, forcing me to restart the computers. I pass my days cursing Catalina for the many times I have to restart the computer daily.

thanks